# How can I bind UIButton.isSelectable with RXSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, rx-swift

```
// This button has different images with for selection and no selection which I configured in storyboard different images for two states.

@IBOutlet weak var selectedRestarunt: UIButton!
    // I am binding isSelected state like this which is working when user taps on button.
    selectedRestarunt.rx.tap.scan(false) { lastState, _ in
        return !lastState
    }
```

Now I have a case I mark `isSelected` manually without tap.

```
selectedRestarunt.isSelected = false/true
```

This shouldn't trigger existing mapping.
This should be mapped somehow, so that I need to some action based on `isSelected` state.
Can anybody explain me how can I achieve this?

Comment: I guess you should write your own wrapper for `isSelected` property. See: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UIButton%2BRx.swift

Answer (score 1):

Take a Variable for this:

SelectedState.value will contain your state

```
let selectedState = Variable(true)
_ = selectedState.asObservable().bindTo(selectedRestarunt.rx.isSelected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RxFeedback](https://github.com/kzaher/RxFeedback) like architecture:

```
...
let isSelected = PublishSubject<Bool>()

enum Event {
    case setIsSelected(Bool)
    case toggle
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Observable.merge(
        isSelected.map { Event.setIsSelected($0) },
        selectedRestarunt.rx.tap.map { _ in Event.toggle }
    ).scan(false) { lastState, event in
        switch event {
        case .setIsSelected(let selected):
            return selected
        case .toggle:
            return !lastState
        }
    }.bind(to: selectedRestarunt.rx.isSelected)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)



    isSelected.onNext(true) // Mark isSelected manually without tap.
}
...
```

Use a `Event` enum to describe state changes, then use `scan` operator to apply the changes.